# How to indicate the position with geom_label

Tags: r

I have a problem with geom_label. When I add geom label to my code the labels appear over the graph for both( line and bars) . I want the labels to be in the same place of the text (geom_text).

This is my general data:

```
structure(list(Dia = structure(c(1583452800, 1583539200, 1583625600, 
1583712000, 1583798400, 1583884800, 1583884800, 1583884800, 1583971200, 
1584057600, 1584057600, 1584144000, 1584230400, 1584316800, 1584403200, 
1584489600, 1584576000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    Hora = structure(c(-2209010400, -2209010400, -2209075200, 
    -2209044600, -2209046400, -2209039200, -2209023600, -2209003200, 
    -2209039500, -2209044600, -2209017600, -2209041000, -2209027800, 
    -2209040160, -2209038720, -2209050000, -2209032000), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Total_Pruebas = c(155, 219, 250, 
    318, 346, 652, 656, 714, 855, 983, 1232, 1545, 1822, 2315, 
    2680, 3075, 3841), Descartados = c(154, 213, 243, 309, 335, 
    640, 641, 697, 833, 955, 1194, 1502, 1751, 2229, 2563, 2930, 
    3607), Positivos = c(1, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12, 15, 17, 22, 28, 
    38, 43, 71, 86, 117, 145, 234), TasaPositivos = c(0.645161290322581, 
    2.73972602739726, 2.8, 2.83018867924528, 3.17919075144509, 
    1.84049079754601, 2.28658536585366, 2.38095238095238, 2.57309941520468, 
    2.84842319430315, 3.08441558441558, 2.7831715210356, 3.89681668496158, 
    3.71490280777538, 4.36567164179105, 4.71544715447155, 6.09216349908878
    ), Pruebas_dia = c(155, 64, 31, 99, 28, 306, 4, 58, 141, 
    128, 249, 313, 277, 493, 365, 395, 766), Recuperados = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 
    1)), row.names = c(NA, 17L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is my code:

```
dat1 <- dat %>%
  mutate(pos_new = Positivos-lag(Positivos,default = 0)) %>%
  group_by(Dia) %>%
  summarise(pos_new = sum(pos_new), tot_pruebas = sum(Pruebas_dia)) %>%
  mutate(cum_pos = cumsum(pos_new))
```

Data to create the graph:

```
structure(list(Dia = structure(c(1583452800, 1583539200, 1583625600, 
1583712000, 1583798400, 1583884800, 1583971200, 1584057600, 1584144000, 
1584230400, 1584316800, 1584403200, 1584489600, 1584576000), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), pos_new = c(1, 5, 1, 2, 2, 6, 5, 16, 
5, 28, 15, 31, 28, 89), tot_pruebas = c(155, 64, 31, 99, 28, 
368, 141, 377, 313, 277, 493, 365, 395, 766), cum_pos = c(1, 
6, 7, 9, 11, 17, 22, 38, 43, 71, 86, 117, 145, 234)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```

Code to create the graph:

```
f1 <- dat1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Dia)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = pos_new, fill = "Nuevos"), stat = "identity", alpha=.98) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = cum_pos, col = "Acumulados"), size=0.75) + 
  geom_label(data = dat1, aes(label =cum_pos , y = Inf), vjust = 1)+
  geom_label(data = dat1, aes(label =pos_new, y = Inf), vjust = 1)+
  geom_point(aes(y = cum_pos), col = "#8B1C62") +
  geom_text(aes(y = pos_new, label = pos_new), vjust = -0.5, col = "#43CD80") +
  geom_text(aes(y = cum_pos, label = cum_pos), vjust = -0.5, col = "#8B1C62") +
  labs(y = "Número de casos reportados", color = " Casos", fill = "", 
       title = paste0("Número de casos confirmados \nhasta: ", Sys.Date())) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Nuevos" = "#43CD80")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Acumulados" = "#8B1C62")) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ .)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = seq(from = as.POSIXct("2020-03-07"), to = as.POSIXct("2020-03-20-20"), by = "3 days"), labels = date_format("%b %d"), sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ., breaks = seq(from = as.POSIXct("2020-03-07"), to = as.POSIXct("2020-03-20-20"), by = "1 days"), name = "Días transcurridos", labels = 1:14))

  plot_grid(f1, rel_widths = c(4,3), labels = c("A","B"))
```

This is what I get:
[image]

This is what I want( like the first graph):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your grpah, because you use `y = Inf` in your `geom_label`, ggplot will place your labels in the maximal y values of your graph (here 234). If you want `geom_label` in the same place than `geom_text`, remove `geom_text` and replace it by `geom_label`

```r
ggplot(dat1, aes( x = Dia))+
  geom_bar(aes(y = pos_new, fill = "Nuevos"), stat = "identity", alpha=.98) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = cum_pos, col = "Acumulados"), size=0.75) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = cum_pos), col = "#8B1C62") +
  geom_label(aes(y = pos_new, label = pos_new), vjust = 0.5) +
  geom_label(aes(y = cum_pos, label = cum_pos), vjust = -0.5) +
  labs(y = "Número de casos reportados", color = " Casos", fill = "", 
       title = paste0("Número de casos confirmados \nhasta: ", Sys.Date()))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Nuevos" = "#43CD80")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Acumulados" = "#8B1C62")) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ .), limits = c(0,265)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "3 days", date_labels = "%b %d",
                   sec.axis = sec_axis(~.,  breaks = seq(from = as.POSIXct("2020-03-07"), to = as.POSIXct("2020-03-20"), by = "1 days"), 
                                       name = "Días transcurridos", labels = 1:13))
```

[image]

Comment: It worked, but I can't see the label of the last geom point( above 145).

Comment: I have edited my answer to include some limits on y axis. Check if it is working now.

Comment: Now I get this error message:Error: Breaks and labels are different lengths

Comment: Yes, compared to your example, I had to change `labels = 1:14` to `labels = 1:13`, I don't know why. Maybe, with your data, if you use your previous code for the last part, it will work.

Comment: Also, check your example, you use in your last line of code "2020-03-20-20"... I think it is an error.

Comment: It worked!. I had to change labels= 1:13 to labels = 1.14. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome ;) Glad ot be able to help :D. I also modify slightly your `scale_x_datetime` to make the use of `date_breaks` and `date_labels` that allow to make your code lighter. For some reasons it does not work for the `sec_axis` part.